# Redundant info in new table?

Tags: database, database-design

A TASK is linked to a TASK_ROLE that associates parties + roles to a specific TASK. I need another table, TASK_RATE, that stores the rate of every party that participoates in a specific TASK. I could get those associations with a FK to TASK_ROLE, but the problem is that a party can have more than one role and can be listed more than once.

```
TASK:
PKIDTASK
1
2
3

TASK_ROLE:
PKIDTASK_ROLE | IDTASK | IDPARTY | IDROLE
  1              1        8         3
  2              1        8         2
  3              1        5         2
  4              1        4         2
```

I tought about creating the table like this

```
TASK_RATE:
PKIDTASK_RATE | IDTASK | IDPARTY
  1              1        8
  2              1        5
  3              1        4
```

IDTASK + IDPARTY are unique, unlike in TASK_ROLE. But wouldn't be this redundant info since PARTY-TASK associations are already defined in TASK_ROLE?

How do I solve this?

Comment: Isn't the rate for each combination of party + role + task just another column on this intersection table?  Why do you need another table?  Is the rate something that changes over time?  Is the rate not dependent on the role?  Please clarify your dependencies.

Comment: Here the PARTY's rate depends only on the TASK, not on the role. So I would have to enter it more than once if I'd keep it in the TASK_ROLE table and a party would have more than one role. Yes, the rate can change over time if the task gets harder for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fully normalize your data model, you probably need something like this:

[image: ERD]

Since parties are assigned to tasks, and these assignments have various other related data, you should start by intersecting the many-to-many between PARTY and TASK.

Other things that you are tracking are offshoots of this intersection.  For example, each party is assigned to one (or more?) roles out of the available party task assignments.

Similarly, For a given party task assignment there will be multiple rates (over time).  The Party Task Rate table will need an effective and expiry date (+time, if appropriate).